# How to initialize a data member of unknown type to a default

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initialization

So I have a class

```
template<typename edge_val_type>
class Graph {
       struct edge {
         int index_;
         edge_val_type v_;
         edge(int index, edge_val_type v) : index_(index), v_(v) {}
}
```

How do I initialize `v_` to some default value? Since at this point the program has no idea what `edge_val_type` is.

Comment: Reverted edit that changed the question after answer has been posted.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
edge()
    : index_( 0 ), v_{}
{}
```

Comment: Like `v_{}`, use `index_{}` to avoid confusion. :D

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I call ```edge(0)``` the compiler complains "no viable constructor".

Comment: If you want a constructor with an argument then you have to define one.

Comment: does edge-val-type have default c-tor? actually is this class, int or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for a default argument to the constructor. You can write:

```
edge(int index, edge_val_type v = {}) : index_(index), v_(v) {}
```

This will allow the usages `edge e(1);` and `e = edge(1);`, and `e = 1;` since this is not an `explicit` constructor.

Comment: The program compiled fine, but it gave a seg_fault when I ran it. Previously, when I had `double v = 0` instead of `edge_val_type v = {}`, it ran fine. Could you think of any reason why that is?

Answer (score -2):

If `v_` is a class and have `default c-tor`, why don't you just omit it from the `c-tor initialize list`?

In that case `v_` will be `default constructed`.

Comment: **−1** “int is default constructed with 0”, no.

Comment: The standard does not require any such initialization. What you have observed is arbitrary, compiler- and option-dependent.

Comment: you are correct. `gcc` seems to initialize to 0. Removed.